# For each row, copy specific cells by predefined columns and paste to values into alternate predefined columns in a seperate worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have to select data from one Excel worksheet and copy into into a different worksheet, however I need to achieve the following during the process of copying my data over:

- For each row of the original worksheet, select cells by column (which I can predefine, perhaps using an array or something).
- Manipulate the data to change the orientation of it in the new worksheet. See screenshot below.

It's difficult to explain exactly what I mean so I hope my screenshot will communicate what I need.

[image]

For each row there is a channel value, I need to order and condense all results by channel. There is also a need to check results against a limit but I can cross that after this problem is solved.

I have my code below, I appreciate that there may be errors as this is my first script. Never mind ordering the data by channel I am struggling so far to even select the columns I want and copy them exactly over to the new worksheet.

The first part of code is to check and create a new worksheet. After that it goes on to define the variables and arrays that I can predefine the columns I want to. It finishes with a loop that checks through x number of rows (although I do want it to iterate for as many rows as there are) and inside that there is another loop for each row, grabs the cell based on my predefined columns.

When debugging, it shows up as an object or application error on the sheet copying function right at the bottom inside the loops. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Where am I going wrong and is there a better way to attack this?

```
Sub Process_Results()

'User defines the worksheets for this script
sourcedatasheet_name = InputBox("Enter the customer data sheet name: ", "Enter Worksheet Name")

For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
    If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(sourcedatasheet_name) Then
        Exit For
    ElseIf (rep = Worksheets.Count) And (LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) <> LCase(sourcedatasheet_name)) Then
        MsgBox "This sheet does not exist!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

destinationdatasheet_name = InputBox("Enter the destination worksheet name to write the data to: ", "Enter Destination Worksheet Name")
For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
    If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(destinationdatasheet_name) Then
        MsgBox "This sheet already exists!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = destinationdatasheet_name

'These are the variables for referencing data sets in the source sheet
Dim source_testmodel
Dim source_testcasename
Dim source_measurementname
Dim source_carrierfrequency
Dim source_limitlow
Dim source_limithigh
Dim source_measuredresult
Dim source_measurementunit

'These are the variables for referencing data set columns in the processed data sheet
Dim destination_testmodel
Dim destination_testcasename
Dim destination_measurementname
Dim destination_carrierfrequency_bottomchannel
Dim destination_carrierfrequency_middlechannel
Dim destination_carrierfrequency_topchannel
Dim destination_measuredresult

'Define the column number and cell column reference for each data set that will be used to retrieve information from the source sheet
source_testmodel = 9
source_testname = 11
source_measurementname = 12
source_measuredcarrierfrequency = 13
source_measurementlimitlow = 15
source_measurementlimithigh = 16
source_measuredresult = 17
source_measurementunit = 18

Dim array_source_fields(8) As Variant
array_source_fields(1) = source_testmodel
array_source_fields(2) = source_testname
array_source_fields(3) = source_measurementname
array_source_fields(4) = source_measuredcarrierfrequency
array_source_fields(5) = source_measurementlimitlow
array_source_fields(6) = source_measurementlimithigh
array_source_fields(7) = source_measuredresult
array_source_fields(8) = source_measurementunit

'Define the column number and cell column reference for each data set that will be used to write information to the processing sheet
destination_testmodel = 1
destination_testname = 2
destination_measurementname = 3
destination_channelbottom = 4
destination_channelmiddle = 5
destination_channeltop = 6

Dim array_processed_fields(6) As Variant
array_processed_fields(1) = destination_testmodel
array_processed_fields(2) = destination_testname
array_processed_fields(3) = destination_measurementname
array_processed_fields(4) = destination_channelbottom
array_processed_fields(5) = destination_channelmiddle
array_processed_fields(6) = destination_channeltop

'Start processing data

Dim y As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long


For x = 1 To 100 'row 'lastrow=activesheet.usedrange.specialcells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    For Each y In array_source_fields 'y = LBound(Application.Transpose(array_source_fields)) To UBound(Application.Transpose(array_source_fields))
        Sheets(sourcedatasheet_name).Cells(x, y).Copy Destination:=Sheets(destinationdatasheet_name).Cells(x, y)
    Next y


Next x




End Sub
```

Comment: I have run the code with 'debug.print(y)' method instead of the 'sheet(arg).Cells(arg).copy' method and it prints all of the correct column numbers as intended. This indicates a definate problem with the 'sheet(arg).Cells(arg).copy'. When I run numbers as arguments for y, instead of using the array, the code works fine but naturally defeats the purpose.

Perhaps the contents of the array are untoward for the sheet(arg).cells(arg).copy method.

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table to solve this problem instead of using VBA?

Comment: Yes, you're over-complicating things. Is the input data sorted by mode ?

Comment: @GlennStevens your comment copied my 1st thought after skimming the question - pivot will do almost all the job.

Comment: The input data sorted by mode, but comes in clusters. So there might be a dozen records for mode 1, followed by mode 2 etc and then returning to a cluster of mode 1 and so on. Ideally there would be an initial check of the records to identify all modes, test names and frequency. Then for each mode in turn it will check which records match, then addittionally within that match which test it comes under and finally setting the data result value, under whichever channel it comes under. I do not know what a pivot table is, however I will be looking into that now too. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: To add to the above. I haven't added extra checking features yet because I want to get the foundation function of 'select information and paste into new worksheet' working like a well oiled machine first. After a brief look into pivot tables this may be what I need. However I welcome any comments. :)

Comment: @GlennStevens thank you for your original pivot table input. While this is a more manual way of selecting and sorting data than I would like in the end, it has helped me a great deal for the many ways I never thought about manipulating my data. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way to solve this! The following three can be found in [this file](https://mega.co.nz/#!rYIHXaKJ!QtaO7y0oYIVIrGJIQRZbhFo4xyZng31aRjWQ1j1EhAM).
[image]

**1. Pivot table**

1. *Insert* tab->*Tables*->PivotTable
2. Select you data as range to analyze and click okay
3. Drag the field `Mode` to "Row Labels" box, "Channel" to the column "Column Labels" and "Results" to "Values"
4. *PivotTable Tools*->*Design* tab->*Layout*->*Grand Totals*->*Off for Rows and Columns*

Done!

**2. Formula**

This solution is only applicable, if the name of the modes and channels are known:

1. Place all the mode names in the first column, all the channel names in the first row, i.e. create header rows. In the below formula, I assume, that the header row is row 1 and the header column is A in sheet2 and that you data is in Sheet1, starting in cell A1
2. In cell B2, enter the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$10,MATCH($A2&"_"&B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10&"_"&Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10,0))
```

This is an array formula, i.e. enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Copy the formula all remaining cells in the table

**3. Macro**

This macro will do the job - though it assumes that modes and channels are sorted. You need to name the top-left cell of your result table `rngHeader` and then run this code:

```
Sub FillTable()
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range
    Dim lngModeCount As Long, lngChannelCount As Long

    Set rngSource = Range("A2")
    Set rngTarget = Range("rngHeader")

    'Clear old result
    With rngTarget
        If .Offset(1) <> "" And .Offset(, 1) <> "" Then
            .Resize(.End(xlDown).Row - .Row + 1, .End(xlToRight).Column - .Column + 1).Clear
            rngTarget = "(cell is named ""rngHeader"")"
        End If
    End With

    While rngSource.Value <> ""
        If rngSource.Offset(-1) <> rngSource Then
            lngModeCount = lngModeCount + 1
            lngChannelCount = 0
            rngTarget.Offset(lngModeCount) = rngSource
            rngTarget.Offset(lngModeCount).Font.Bold = True
        End If
        lngChannelCount = lngChannelCount + 1
        If lngModeCount = 1 Then
            rngTarget.Offset(, lngChannelCount) = rngSource.Offset(, 2)
            rngTarget.Offset(, lngChannelCount).Font.Bold = True
        End If
        rngTarget.Offset(lngModeCount, lngChannelCount) = rngSource.Offset(, 3)
        Set rngSource = rngSource.Offset(1)
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: All three methods have shown me different solutions with different advantages! I have found the Pivot Table to be the best solution overall solution because of it's flexibility to manipulate data in other ways which are also useful to me. The macro has given me much insight into more effective coding. Thanks very much for your help with this!

Answer (score 1):

By the way, here is some code that would do what you want:

```
Const FIRST_CELL_IN_SOURCE_DATA = "$A$4"
Const FIRST_CELL_IN_DEST_DATA = "$A$2"

Const COL_SOURCE_MODE = 0
Const COL_SOURCE_DESC = 1
Const COL_SOURCE_CHANNEL = 2
Const COL_SOURCE_RESULT = 3
Const COL_SOURCE_LIMIT = 4

Const COL_DEST_MODE = 1
Const COL_DEST_DESC = 1
Const COL_DEST_RESULT = 4
Const COL_DEST_FIRST_CHANNEL = 3

Const ROW_DEST_HEADER = 1

Private wksSource As Worksheet
Private wksDest As Worksheet

Sub Process_Results()

If GetSourceSheet = False Then Exit Sub
If CreateDestinationSheet = False Then Exit Sub
CopyDataSet

End Sub

Private Function GetSourceSheet() As String

'User defines the worksheets for this script
sourcedatasheet_name = InputBox("Enter the customer data sheet name: ", "Enter Worksheet Name")

For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
    If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(sourcedatasheet_name) Then
        Exit For
    ElseIf (rep = Worksheets.Count) And (LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) <> LCase(sourcedatasheet_name)) Then
        MsgBox "This sheet does not exist!"
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

Set wksSource = Sheets(sourcedatasheet_name)
GetSourceSheet = True

End Function

Private Function CreateDestinationSheet() As String

destinationdatasheet_name = InputBox("Enter the destination worksheet name to write the data to: ", "Enter Destination Worksheet Name")
For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
    If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(destinationdatasheet_name) Then
        MsgBox "This sheet already exists!"
        Exit Function
    End If
Next

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = destinationdatasheet_name

Set wksDest = Sheets(destinationdatasheet_name)
AddHeaders
CreateDestinationSheet = True

End Function

Private Sub CopyDataSet()

Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestRange As Range

Set rngSourceRange = wksSource.Range(FIRST_CELL_IN_SOURCE_DATA)
Set rngDestRange = wksDest.Range(FIRST_CELL_IN_DEST_DATA)
rngDestRange.Activate

Do Until rngSourceRange.Value = ""
    CopyRowToDest rngSourceRange, rngDestRange
    Set rngSourceRange = rngSourceRange.Offset(1)
Loop

End Sub

Private Sub AddHeaders()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wksDest.Cells(ROW_DEST_HEADER, 1)

rng.Value = "Mode"
rng.Offset(, 1).Value = "Test"

End Sub

Private Function GetColumnForChannel(ByVal Channel As String) As Long

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wksDest.Cells(ROW_DEST_HEADER, COL_DEST_FIRST_CHANNEL)

Do Until rng.Value = ""
    If rng.Value = Channel Then
        GetColumnForChannel = rng.Column - 1
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
Loop

rng.Value = Channel
GetColumnForChannel = rng.Column - 1

End Function

Private Sub MoveToModeRow(ByVal Mode As String)

If ActiveCell.Value = Mode Then Exit Sub

If ActiveCell.Address = FIRST_CELL_IN_DEST_DATA And ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.Value = Mode
    Exit Sub
End If

If Val(ActiveCell.Value) < Val(Mode) And ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value = "" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate
    ActiveCell.Value = Mode
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wksDest.Range(FIRST_CELL_IN_DEST_DATA)

Do Until rng.Value = ""
    If rng.Value = Mode Then
        rng.Activate
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
Loop

rng.Value = Mode
rng.Activate

End Sub



Private Sub CopyRowToDest(ByRef rngSourceRange As Range, ByRef rngDestRange As Range)

MoveToModeRow rngSourceRange.Offset(, COL_SOURCE_MODE).Value

Dim lngCol As Long
lngCol = GetColumnForChannel(rngSourceRange.Offset(, COL_SOURCE_CHANNEL).Value)

ActiveCell.Offset(, lngCol).Value = rngSourceRange.Offset(, COL_SOURCE_RESULT).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(, COL_DEST_DESC).Value = rngSourceRange.Offset(, COL_SOURCE_DESC).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: This code seemed to only produce the first result for each mode, however after looking through the code I think it won't require too much adapting to get this working exactly as I need it. Thanks very much for your help, this solution has given me many ideas to code in different ways. Thank you very much for your help Neil!